# Vue transition-group not animating properly when first list item is spliced from list

Tags: vue.js, animation, transition, vuejs-transition-group

I am struggling to figure out why my transition group is not animating properly on the removal of the **first** element from a list. I tried producing a minimal, reproducible example to share on my local machine first and was successful. I then copied the same code to CodeSandbox to share with StackOverflow but the issue no longer exists for some reason.

Here is the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/transition-group-85q07?file=/src/App.vue) example which works properly, and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDSSn.gif) is a recording of the same code producing the issue when served on my local machine.

In the recording, you'll see the first two elements are removed properly. They translate right and fade out, and the subsequent elements smoothly transition upwards to fill the voided space.

However, when I remove the first element on my next two clicks, the leaving element transitions properly but the subsequent elements **jump instantly**.

The issue is produced in Chrome, Firefox, and IE. Any idea why it's working properly in CodeSandbox but not my machine despite similar code?

Comment: Did you ever work out why this was happening? I'm running in to the same problem

Comment: I ended up creating a new Vue instance and copying my code over and it worked. I'm still not sure what the root cause of the issue was.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I still can't figure out what's causing it for me either. Might have to try the same.